# What causes Windows Workflow to end up throwing "Could not load file or assembly"?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation

I have a few workflows running, and after about ~8 months to a year, I start getting:

```
Message: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\TEMP\4s4yy32u\4s4yy32u.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Thrown. If I restart my windows service, it continues working again for a few days and then starts again.

If I spin up a brand new instance of Windows Server, the issue goes away for ~8 months to a year.

Googling or even searching on SO is difficult because for file/assembly not found it's usually to do with an actual missing dependency, which isn't the case here. This appears to be the file generated by WWF when the workflow is executed.

Anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: May be a long shot, but do you have an automated process which clears the temp directory, maybe based on age of files etc?

Comment: No automated process, but I just happen to be looking at the temp folder and there's ~150k folders in there... But I can't imagine that would be a problem? There's still ~30gb of free space on the machine.